# refactor linq expression to remove duplicate code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have the following piece of code and I try to refactor this to remove the duplicate code. However every time I try to refactor it I get stuck. Is there someone who can help me out with this issue.

```
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ObjectSort<T>(this IQueryable<T> entities, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, string order = "asc")
    {
        var sortOrder = order == "asc" ? SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
        return entities.ObjectSort(expression, sortOrder);
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ObjectThenBy<T>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> entities, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, string order = "asc")
    {
        var sortOrder = order == "asc" ? SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
        return entities.ObjectThenBy(expression, sortOrder);
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ObjectSort<T>(this IQueryable<T> entities, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, SortOrder order = SortOrder.Ascending)
    {
        var unaryExpression = expression.Body as UnaryExpression;
        if (unaryExpression != null)
        {
            var propertyExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
            var parameters = expression.Parameters;

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTime>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(newExpression) : entities.OrderByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTime?>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(newExpression) : entities.OrderByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(int))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(newExpression) : entities.OrderByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(int?))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int?>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(newExpression) : entities.OrderByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(bool))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(newExpression) : entities.OrderByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException("Object type resolution not implemented for this type");
        }
        return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(expression) : entities.OrderByDescending(expression);
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ObjectThenBy<T>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> entities, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, SortOrder order = SortOrder.Ascending)
    {
        var unaryExpression = expression.Body as UnaryExpression;
        if (unaryExpression != null)
        {
            var propertyExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
            var parameters = expression.Parameters;

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTime>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.ThenBy(newExpression) : entities.ThenByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTime?>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.ThenBy(newExpression) : entities.ThenByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(int))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.ThenBy(newExpression) : entities.ThenByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(int?))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int?>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.ThenBy(newExpression) : entities.ThenByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(bool))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.ThenBy(newExpression) : entities.ThenByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException("Object type resolution not implemented for this type");
        }
        return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.ThenBy(expression) : entities.ThenByDescending(expression);
    }
```

Please note the difference is the OrderBy and the ThenBy... The rest is exactly the same. Hopefully someone knows a way to refactor this. I was trying to create a Func parameter to pass the OrderBy or the ThenBy method. However everything I try I get stuck.

Comment: Why do you need to determine the type first if the code is exactly the same for each type?  You only have to send `Func<T, object>` to your method.

Comment: Isn't that already implemented in Linq? OrderBy, OrderByDescending, ThenBy, ThenByDescending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference between OrderBy and ThenBy is that OrderBy expects IQueryable, and ThenBy expects IOrderedqueryAble.

Now to use OrderBy or ThenBy, you need to figure out whether the collection is IQueryable or IOrderedQueryAble.

After that if it is IQueryable, call OrderBy. If it is IOrderedQueryable, call ThenBy (after casting as IOrderedQueryable.

**Refactored code snippet becomes**

```
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ObjectSortRefactored<T>(this IQueryable<T> entities, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, SortOrder order = SortOrder.Ascending)
    {
        var unaryExpression = expression.Body as UnaryExpression;
        if (unaryExpression != null)
        {
            var propertyExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
            var parameters = expression.Parameters;

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTime>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(newExpression) : entities.OrderByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTime?>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(newExpression) : entities.OrderByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(int))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(newExpression) : entities.OrderByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(int?))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int?>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(newExpression) : entities.OrderByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(bool))
            {
                var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(newExpression) : entities.OrderByDescending(newExpression);
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException("Object type resolution not implemented for this type");
        }
        if(entities.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IOrderedQueryable<T>)))
                return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? (entities as IOrderedQueryable<T>).ThenBy(expression) : (entities as IOrderedQueryable<T>).ThenByDescending(expression);

        return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(expression) : entities.OrderByDescending(expression);
    }
```

I have not tested the above snippet though.